# Minor Upgrade + Full Installer

Tags: windows-installer, installation, upgrade

I have a doubt regarding minor upgrade. Suppose there is a MSI installer AZ 1.0, and multiple minor updates(MSP) have been delivered as AZ 1.1, AZ 1.2 and AZ 1.3.
Now there are multiple users, many of those have different versions of the same installer and now there are some new users who have no version of AZ app installed.
While delivering AZ 1.4 how should I make sure that all the users get updated/installed with AZ 1.4.
Note: AZ 1.0 was a MSI and AZ 1.1, AZ 1.2, AZ 1.3 were MSP installers, and AZ 1.4 should be a MSI as a complelety new user should be able to install AZ 1.4. Thanks in advance for your assistance.

Comment: As long as you are following the rules that ensure a minor upgrade can succeed (mostly just component rules), each of those can be built to be install successfully over any previous version.

Comment: Thanks Michael, do you mean to say that if i run the complete MSI over a machine that already has the older version of the installer and the updates, the newer files in the MSI will get installed? I am not sure about this because minor upgrade would need switches like REINSTALL & REINSTALLMODE during installation.

Comment: InstallShield's bootstrap will pass those automatically; if you're not using it,  you will indeed have to provide them some other way.

Comment: Okay. I wasn't sure about how installation will happen in both the above scenarios..thanks, will test this.
Also can you please confirm if I am creating a basic MSI project(Installshield) that gives me a setup as a final output. Do you mean to convey that this setup will pass those properties automatically?

Answer (score 1):

If you want AZ 1.4 to be an MSI for new users as well as including all the previous fixes, then build it as an MSI (with all the fixes) and make it a major upgrade that will replace all previous versions, including patched versions. Without knowing what tool you are using to build your MSI there is no specific answer, but the MSI Upgrade table and upgrade mechanism can specify a range of previous versions and upgrade them all.

The problem with delivering the new MSI as a complete MSI and as a minor upgrade is that new users can just install the MSI but existing users need to install it with a command line, typically REINSTALL=ALL REINSTALLMODE=vomus and a major upgrade just works without this requirement. One way to do this is with a launcher program that detects any existing installed products and launches the MSI with the command line options when necessary.

Comment: Thanks for your assistance, I am using InstallShield to build MSI, MSP. The requirement is such that I cannot implement major upgrade. I want the new users to get complete installer and existing users to get only the updates in the previous one. But as you mentioned above I am not sure how to install for existing users as minor upgrade requires the switches REINSTALL & REINSTALLMODE